# Cant inject Spring dependencies to both Spock and Spring at same time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spock

I'm having troubles with setting up my tests. I'm using latest version of SpringBoot and Spock Framework. First of all, I'm not configuring my beans "traditional" way. All my classes in package except `Facade` are package-scoped. I'm not using `@Component`, `@Service`, etc.

The only one class Im injecting is `Repository`. Let me show you my `Configuration` class

```
@Configuration
class SurveyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    SurveyFacade surveyFacade(SurveyRepository surveyRepository) {
        ConversionUtils conversionUtils = new ConversionUtils();
        SurveyValidator surveyValidator = new SurveyValidator();
        SurveyCreator surveyCreator = new SurveyCreator(surveyRepository, conversionUtils, surveyValidator);
        return new SurveyFacade(surveyCreator);
    }
}
```

It works fine, I'v tested all scenarios manually (sending POST to certain endpoint). Let me show you example method from `SurveyCreator` class I want to test.

```
SurveyDTO createSurvey(final SurveyDTO surveyDTO) throws ValidationException, PersistenceException {
    Survey survey = conversionUtils.surveyToEntity(surveyDTO);
    surveyValidator.validate(survey);        
    Optional<Survey> savedInstance = Optional.ofNullable(surveyRepository.save(survey)); //Will throw NullPtr
    return savedInstance.map(conversionUtils::surveyToDTO)
            .orElseThrow(PersistenceException::new);
}
```

Like I said, during runtime it works fine.  So lets move on to tests

```
@SpringBootTest
class SurveyFacadeTest extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    private SurveyRepository surveyRepository
    private SurveyFacade surveyFacade = new SurveyConfiguration().surveyFacade(this.surveyRepository)

    def "should inject beans"() {
        expect:
            surveyRepository != null
            surveyFacade != null
    }
    def "should create survey and return id"() {
        given:
           Long id
        when:
            id = surveyFacade.createSurvey(SampleSurveys.validSurvey())
        then:
            id != surveyFacade
    }
}
```

First test passes, so I understand I got everything ok for tests. But, I'm getting NullPointer in my java code in method I posted above. Looks like `SurveyRepository` isnt injected into java code during tests, because thats the one that causes this exception... Any ideas how to work around that, to have my `Repository` injected in both Spring application and Spock tests?

Comment: any reasons against: `@Autowired private SurveyFacade surveyFacade;` ? ..if not: "this is my answer" ;)

Comment: No reason to do that, I'm confused why I actually didnt do it before. Thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: That's what I like about Spring (framework ... *works like charm* ..mostly&even more with the time:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no reasons against, I recommend you to run the test on the "underlying bean" (and not a manually created instance):

```
@Autowired
private SurveyFacade surveyFacade;
```